# What is this wearable camera support from the 1970s or 1980s?

Tags: equipment-identification

[image]

This belonged to my Dad and is probably from the 70's or 80's. I want to find a new home for it (if it is still useful) but I don't know what it is exactly. It appears to be some sort of steadying support which you wear but i'm not sure

Comment: I don't know for sure - but I would guess a monopod of some sort, with the bottom of the image being a stabilizing foot and the top being where the camera gets mounted. I would also guess that the straps aren't really indicative of "wearable" gear, but are simply carrying straps. Perhaps a couple pictures from different angles would give more detail. Do any parts extend/rotate/etc.? The top part in particular looks like it might be some sort of pan/tilt mechanism with a handle.

Comment: Can you provide more photos of the object, from different angles? What do the buttons on the side do? Can you provide some measurements?

Comment: Without a quick-detach mounting plate needed to attach the camera to the top of the device, it's not very usable as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a [SLIK EZ HOLD chestpod](http://www.glagencies.co.za/products/Slik/heads-and-accessories/slik-617450-ez-hold-chest-pod).

[image]

Details online are very scarce, so I would presume the model has been discontinued, but the central column is very similar to the current line of [SLIK Easi-pod monopods](http://www.slik.com/MP-EASI-POD.html). The manufacturer may have more information about the chestpod if you need its specifications.

I could not find any images of the SLIK chestpod in use, but the design is not dissimilar to [this one by Novoflex](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/240748-REG/Novoflex_PISTOCK_C_Chest_Shoulder_Pod_Reduces.html) which may give a clearer idea of how the parts would be positioned in use.

[image]